# Multiple comparison operators on a single line

Tags: python, comparison, variable-assignment, logical-operators

I'm taking an intro to python course, and there was one question on a quiz that I could not make heads or tails of. Given this code, the question asks what value will be assigned to x:

```
z = 2
y = 1
x = y < z or z > y and y > z or z < y
```

I'm really confused about where the assignment is in this statement. Should I read this as "x equals y if y is less than z"? I can't even begin to understand how to read "or" and "and" in this context.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course, it returns a boolean (facepalm). Thanks for the tip. I got confused by the syntax and didn't even consider testing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to read it like this, x will be a boolean (true or false) and so will each of the comparison expressions

```
z = 2
y = 1

x = y < z or z > y and y > z or z < y

x = ( (y<z) or ((z>y) and (y>z)) or (z<y) )
x = ( True or (True and False) or False )
x = True
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `and` has higher precedence than `or`, so

```
y < z or z > y and y > z or z < y
```

is the same as

```
y < z or (z > y and y > z) or z < y
          # always False
```

is the same as

```
y < z or z < y
```

is the same as

```
y != z
```

Answer (score 0):

In `python`, `and` have higher priority than `or`. So, `and` will be evaluated first (left to right) then `or` will be evaluated (left to right), unless there are `()`.

So, in your case, first thing to be evaluated are `z > y and y > z`, and steps follows like:

```py
x = y < z or (True and False) or z < y
x = (y < z or False) or z < y
x = (True or False) or z < y
x = True or False
x = True
```